# Code for getting data from Google spreadsheet to my app has suddenly stopped working

Tags: java, android, html, android-webview, spreadsheet

I'm using this code to get data from google spreadsheet to web application. It was working fine and now it's not getting any data.

Even other pages which are using the same code and other spreadsheet urls have stopped working. I don't know how to solve this please help me.

Here is the code I have used in my project.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,700);

html,body{
  height:101%;   
}

body{
  background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/220072/pexels-photo-220072.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed; 

}

*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.nn-alert{
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:20px;
  background:rgba(51, 59, 70, 0.5);
  border:1px solid #111;
  border-radius:3px;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 24px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
    inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4),
    inset 0 10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 -5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
    0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  width:250px;
  height:auto;
  padding:5px 10px;
  color:white;
  font-size:12px;
  text-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  transition:all .5s ease;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.nn-alert.pink, .nn-alert.neatnait{
  background: rgba(255, 0, 102, 0.7);
}
.nn-alert.purple{
  background: rgba(37, 0, 102, 0.7);
}
.nn-alert.blue{
  background: rgba(24, 90, 207, 0.7);
}
.nn-alert.glass{
  background: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.27); 
}



.nn-alert .fa{
  font-size:2em;
  width:1em;
  float:left;
  margin:7px 10px 0 0px;
  text-align:center;
}

.nn-alert p{
  margin:6px 0;
}

.nn-alert:hover{
  opacity:0.5;
}
/*
.nn-alert:hover .nn-alert:after{
  content:"asdf";
}
*/
h1, h3{

  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight:100;
  text-shadow:0 1px 15px #fff;
  margin-bottom:2em;
}

h1{
  width:250px;
  margin:auto;
  color:white;
}
.neatnait-love{
  width:250px;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:5em;
  font-weight:300;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-shadow:0 5px 20px #000;
  color:white;
  background:#111;
  padding:2em 6em 2em 4em;
}

a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#f06;
  border-bottom:1px solid white;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  transition:border .5s ease;
}

a:hover{
  border-color:#111;
  color:#f06;
  border-bottom:4px solid white;
}


.hide{
  height:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.colors{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  padding:1em;
  color:white;
  font-size:11px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.thumb{
  width:15px;
  height:15px;

  border:1px solid white;
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
}

.color.neatnait .thumb{
  background:#f06;
}
.color.purple .thumb{
  background: rgba(37, 0, 102, 0.7);
}
.color.blue .thumb{
  background: rgba(24, 90, 207, 0.7); 
}
.color.glass .thumb{
  background: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.27); 
}


</style>


</head>
<body class="bg">

<script>

var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbygukdW3tt8sCPcFDlkMnMuNu9bH5fpt7bKV50p2bM/exec?id=*************************&sheet=********');
ourRequest.onload = function(){
var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
//console.log(ourData["data"]);
//console.log(ourData.data[0].Name);

for (i in ourData.sender){
document.getElementById("spotlight").innerHTML =  ourData.sender[i].spotlight + document.getElementById("spotlight").innerHTML;


    }

};
ourRequest.send();


</script>

<center>

<h1 id="addhere">Spotlight</h1>

  <div id="spotlight">

</div>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you provided has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean to say in my android app there is a WebView in which I have useing these code.